# push all elements of list to stack in scala

Tags: scala

Is it possible to push elements of a list into a stack in scala?

I know it's possible to push multiple elements at once such as

```
val stack = scala.collection.mutable.Stack[Int]()
stack.push(1,2,3,4)
```

But if I have a defined list or other collection, I can't do

```
val l1 = List[Int](5,6,7)
stack.push(l1)
```

What would be the scala idiomatic way of accomplishing this?

Comment: Do you want a mutable or immutable stack? If immutable, then why not just use `List`, as is. To _pop_ an element you just access `head` (assuming you _pushed_ your elements into the `List` using a prepend operation ie. `::`.

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve it with [pushAll](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/Stack.html#pushAll[B%3E:A](xs:scala.collection.TraversableOnce[B]):scala.collection.immutable.Stack[B]) method.

```scala
val stack = scala.collection.mutable.Stack[Int]()
val l1 = List[Int](5,6,7)
stack.pushAll(l1)
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the last (2.12.0) spec `mutable.Stack` is deprecated and it is advised to use `var List` instead. Please see [Stack](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/mutable/Stack.html) api.

```
(Since version 2.12.0) Stack is an inelegant and potentially 
poorly-performing wrapper around List. Use a List assigned 
to a var instead.
```

So, in case you'd like to replace Stack with a mutable List your example will look like

```
var stack = List.empty[Int]
val l1 = List[Int](5,6,7)
stack = stack ++: l1
```

Comment: Actually, if you're going to push to, and pop from, the `head` of a mutable `List` (which, I think makes sense) then the equivalent of `pushAll()` would be: `stack = l1.reverse ++: stack`

Answer (score 1):

Create stack with with some known values

```
val stack = scala.collection.mutable.Stack[Int](1,2,3,4)
```

Or init with some collection.

```
val l = List(1,2,3,4)
val stack = scala.collection.mutable.Stack[Int](l:_*)
```

Or use pushAll like @adamywy recommended.

```
val stack = scala.collection.mutable.Stack[Int]()

val l = List(1,2,3,4)
stack.pushAll(l)
```